# Validate 2 forms on one page

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to incorporate 2 forms into the one page but the php treats the 2 forms as one and I am stumped as to how I can separate them. Thanks in advance for your help. Here is my html for form 1:

```
<div id="message">
            <h3>Message Us</h3>
            <form action="?" method="POST" onsubmit="return saveScrollPositions(this);">
                <input type="hidden" name="scrollx" id="scrollx" value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" name="scrolly" id="scrolly" value="0" />
                <div id="msgbox1">
                    <label for="msgname">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="msgname" name="msgname" placeholder=" Required" />

                    <label for="msgemail">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="msgemail" name="msgemail" placeholder=" Required" />

                <label for="msgphone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" id="msgphone" name="msgphone" placeholder="" />

                    <label for= "msgtopic">Topic:</label>
                    <select id="msgtopic" name="msgtopic">
                        <option value="general">General</option>
                        <option value="stud">Property Price Enquiry</option>
                        <option value="sale">Bull Sale Enquiry</option> 
                    </select>
                </div><!--- msg box 1 -->
                <div id="msgbox2">    
                    <textarea id="emailmessage" name="emailmessage" rows="7" colums="25" placeholder="Your Message?"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
                    <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback2; ?></p>
                </div><!--- msg box 2 -->
            </form><!--- end form -->
        </div><!--- end message -->
```

The php for form 1:

```
  <?php 

$to = '418@hotmail.com.au';
$subject = 'Morrison Property Group website enquiry';

$msgname = $_POST ['msgname'];
$msgemail = $_POST ['msgemail'];
$msgphone = $_POST ['msgemail'];
$msgtopic = $_POST ['msgtopic'];
$message = $_POST ['emailmessage'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

This is a message from $msgname
Topic: $msgtopic 

Message: $emailmessage

From $name
Phone: $msgphone 
Email: $msgemail

EMAIL;

$header = ' From: $msgemail ';

if($_POST){
    if($msgname == '' || $msgemail == '' || $emailmessage == ''){
        $feedback = '*Please fill out all the fields'; 
    }else {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
        $feedback2 = 'Thanks for the message. <br /> We will contact you soon!';
    }
}
?>
```

The html for form 2:

```
<div id="mail">
                <h3>Sign Up to MPG mail...</h3>
                <div id= "form">
                    <form action="?" method="POST" onsubmit="return saveScrollPositions(this);">
                        <input type="hidden" name="scrollx" id="scrollx" value="0" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="scrolly" id="scrolly" value="0" />
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
                        </fieldset>                    
                    </form><!--End Form -->
                    <p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
                </div><!-- End Form -->
            </div><!-- End mail -->
```

And the php for form 2:

```
    <?php 

$to = '@morrisonpg.com.au';
$subject = 'Sign Up';

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Please add $name with the email $email to your mailing list.

EMAIL;

$header = ' From: $name ';

if($_POST){
    if($name == '' || $email == ''){
        $feedback = '*Please fill out all the fields'; 
    }else {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
        $feedback = 'Thanks for signing up. <br /> You will receive correspondence soon!';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are sending each form to same php handler but there is no spearation. See my answer for further detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should simplly add the name for the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
```

In the PHP:

```
<?php if($_POST['submit']=='Sign Up'){ /* signup code */}else{ /* other code */}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give different names to each form and put one hidden element in each form like;

```
 <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="1" />
```

And for form 2;

```
 <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="2" />
```

And in your php check `form_type` and act for each form.

```
 $type = $_POST["form_type"];
 if ($type == 1) {
    // Code for form 1
 } else if ($type == 2){
    // Code for form 2
 } else {
    die("Invalid form");
 }
```